# What is the cause of this unexpected additional character in C?

Tags: c, string, memory

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    static char foo[32];
    memset(foo, '0', sizeof(foo));
    printf("%s %d\n", foo, sizeof(foo));

    return 0;
}
```

I receive the following output:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000☺ 32
```

The string length is 33, while its size is 32 bytes, so it seems that the "smiley-face" character at index 32 comes from some piece of unallocated memory. I'm confused as to what is going on here, and I can't seem to word a search query well enough to find what I'm looking for. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Q: so it seems that the "smiley-face" character at index 32 comes from some piece of unallocated memory..  Yup.  You've initialized all 32 characters of your 32-character array to the ASCII digit '0' ... but you forgot to null terminate the string!  The last character of a C string must be a binary "0".  The result is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: "The string length is 33" --> `foo` is **not** a _string_ as it lacks a _null character_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` in `printf()` expects a pointer to *strings*, which means "a sequence of characters *terminated by a null-character*" in C.

All of the bytes in the buffer `foo` is filled by `'0'`, so there are no terminating null-character in the buffer and `printf()` will go out-of-range to find a terminating null-character.

You should specify the length to print when you want to print a sequence of characters which is not a string (one without terminating null-character).

Also note that `sizeof` returns `size_t` while `%d` format specifier and the length to specify (if it is given as an argument). Passing data having wrong type invokes *undefined behavior*. The correct format specifier to print `size_t` is `%zu`. (Note that `size_t` is unsigned).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    static char foo[32];
    memset(foo, '0', sizeof(foo));
    printf("%.*s %zu\n", (int)sizeof(foo), foo, sizeof(foo));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I suspected it has something to do with the terminating character in a string but I couldn't pinpoint it. On a side note, why is this answer getting downvoted?

Comment: @SeanXie NMDV, yet I suspect printing an array of characters with `"%.*s"` is unusual for some.  This is the correct solution for a 32 byte array with 32 `'0'`.  Alternatives include making `foo[33];` a _string_ and using `"%s"`.